# unable to access rest endpoint in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am facing issues while run jar using
flink run ./path-to-jar
I have created one rest end point using the below code
Local web server created using java API.
I am unable to access the rest end point using http://localhost:9001/xyz

I am able to access while run from IDE. and its working perfectly.

can someone provide way, how can I access when we run jar using flink run command.

```
public class RunLocalWebServer {

    HttpServer server;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            RunLocalWebServer localServer = new RunLocalWebServer();
            localServer.startServer();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void startServer() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Starting Web Server to server xyz..");

        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(
                "localhost", 8001), 0);

        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(10);

        // XYZ handler uses the XYZHTTPHandler class
        server.createContext("/xyz", new XYZHTTPHandler());
        server.setExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Started Local web server");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by using detached mode and CountDownLatch java API.

```
./flink run --detached /path/to/sample.jar
```

Add the below lines in last RunLocalWebServer.java in startServer method.

```
CountDownLatch c = new CountDownLatch();
c.await();
```

By using this you can access the rest endpoint which is configured by above question.